# Theme function overrides and preprocess functions - for the non-programmer

Tags: theming

I'm trying to get my head around what these are. I've read a few articles and posts introducing Drupal theming where these are mentioned, but I'm struggling to understand what they are and what they do - each explanation I've seen so far (including on Drupal.org) makes an assumption that I know PHP or have programming experience.

Could someone explain in layman's terms or point to a good, simple-to-understand explanation, please?

Comment: Have you reviewed this drupal node? It's very comprehensive: http://drupal.org/node/341628

Comment: @chrisjlee The above node even says "If you are not already familiar with PHP, the process might seem somewhat intimidating, but it generally does not require that you understand anything about actually writing PHP."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, the theme layer *is* PHP, so you will need a minimal understanding of some programming concepts (e.g. what a [function](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/functions) is). Especially since you will have to write some basic PHP within them. So the following might not be perfectly suited for a non programmer initally, but I tried to link everything so you can read more about it. Also, add comments if something is not clear.

The theme layer builds upon naming conventions on how to name your functions to have them called automatically. Similar to the so called [hooks](http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/group/hooks/7&rct=j&q=drupal%20hooks&ei=eqIaTon-Mo_PsgarpvGpDw&usg=AFQjCNF07tSsHy2WDC-_0Sg0NbCJvs4iUg). At least preprocess functions are a special variant of hooks. I'll come back to that later.

Any module can register theme functions (or templates) by using [hook_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/hook_theme) (You don't need to understand how that works right now). ) For example,  it can basically tell Drupal that it has a theme function called `mymodule_fancything`. This module is then also responsible for providing the default theme function, which is prefixed with `theme_`. In the previous example, that module needs to define the function `theme_mymodule_fancything`.

Later on, that, or any other, module can call that theme function with the function [theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme/7) like this: `theme('mymodule_fancything', $arg1, $arg2);` (D6) or `theme('mymodule_fancything`, array('arg1' => $arg1, 'arg2' => $arg2));` (D7).

Then, that function will figure out which function to call. First, it will check if there is a theme override for the active theme. That means, a function that is prefixed with `themename_` instead of `theme_`. So in our example, `themename_mymodule_fancything`. If it finds that function it will call that and if not, it falls back to `theme_mymodule_fancything`.

As you've seen in the example code, you usually pass a number of arguments to a theme function or a template which contains the data that should be displayed. Sometimes you want to further process/change that information before it's passed to the theme function or the template. Or a module wants to change something of another module. Also because theme functions/templates should not contain any complex PHP processing. Unlike with the mentioned hooks (which can be implemented by all modules and all are called), a theme function can only by overridden once.

That is where preprocess functions come into play. They are invoked by the theme() and receive all arguments passed to that theme function (only in D7) or template. Then they can be altered/extended in any way. There is a large number of rules what preprocess functions are called when but basically, you usually only use one that is specific for a given theme function/template. That looks like this: `name_preprocess_hook(&$vars)`. `name` can be the name of a module or theme and `hook` is the name of the template/theme function. There are tons of examples for preprocess functions in core, search for [*preprocess*](http://api.drupal.org/api/search/7/_preprocess_).

Remember to rebuild theme registry (e.g. with devel.module or by re-saving the theme configuration form).

Comment: crikey... I think I'm going to need to cover a rudimentary understanding of PHP to get my head around your explanation. The concepts involved are just too nebulous and complex for me to understand, unfortunately.

I've been trying to find a way to learn PHP as part of a Drupal project, but it looks increasingly likely that I'll have to learn PHP first, separately, before moving on to understanding Drupal theming a bit more.

Thanks for your in-depth explanation, anyway, Berdir - much appreciated :)

Comment: I'm aware that it might not be easy to understand without knowing PHP. But the thing is, as mentioned above, this *is* PHP. Even if you understand the basic concept (which is not that complicated), withing those functions, you will write PHP. No way around that. So you need to understand a bit PHP (basic stuff like accessing/printing variables, conditions and loops, array/object structures and how to access them) anyway.