# How remove DIV elements in rendered search form in theme designing

Tags: theming, search

## the rendered search form result in drupal 6 is

```
<form id="search-theme-form" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/drupalcms626/%40q%3Dcontact">
    <div>
        <div id="edit-search-theme-form-1-wrapper" class="form-item">
        <label for="edit-search-theme-form-1">Search this site: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-text" title="Enter the terms you wish to search for." value="" size="15" id="edit-search-theme-form-1" name="search_theme_form" maxlength="128">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="form-submit" value="Search" id="edit-submit" name="op">
    <input type="hidden" value="form-40ac94eba9b49795082bf8daf59eae58" id="form-40ac94eba9b49795082bf8daf59eae58" name="form_build_id">
    <input type="hidden" value="e030363baad8b89de124a2d09bcbeaa7" id="edit-search-theme-form-form-token" name="form_token">
    <input type="hidden" value="search_theme_form" id="edit-search-theme-form" name="form_id">
    </div>
</form>
```

=======================================
Now I want to remove all DIV tags in rendered result.

I mean

```
 1. <div>
 2. <div id="edit-search-theme-form-1-wrapper" class="form-item">
 3. </div>
 4. </div>
```

elements

anybody knows how can I do this via theme functions in template.php or page.tpl.php or modifying other *.tpl.php files.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

There are two theme functions you need to override:

1. [`theme_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_form/7), in which the wrapping `<div>` is hard-coded with this line:

   ```
   return '<form' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '><div>' . $element['#children'] . '</div></form>';
   ```
2. [`theme_form_element()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_form_element) which contains all of the extra `<div>`s you're trying to get rid of.

The latter is quite a long function so there may well be some duplication, but I don't know how else you would do this.

Comment: If anyone wonders how to override the theme functions in module instead theme(template.php), then here is an excellent article:
https://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/avoiding-templatephp-doom-or-overriding-theme-functions-modules

Answer (score 2):

you may create a template for your form and there you may render what you want

like:

```
function mymodule_form_alter($form,&$form_state,$form_id){
switch($form_id){
case 'search-theme-form':

$form['#theme'] = 'my_theme_function'
}

}

function mymodule_theme($vars){
return ('my_theme_function'=>array(
'render element'=>'form',
'template' => 'my-theme-function'
),
);}
```

then create a template file with name my-theme-function.tpl.php  in your module's folder or current theme's templates folder and clear the cache.

everything from your form array is available in your tpl.php file as $form variable which you may render something from it. If you want to change anything for your form array do it in your form alter hook.

Comment: the signature of hook_form_alter() was different for me in Drupal 7, so it was not finding my custom hook. After, changing it to function mymodule_form_alter(&$form,$form_state,$form_id), it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [theme developer module](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer). It tells you which theme function and/or template to use to modify a certain part of your page.

Comment: Thanks at first. I know it is template_preprocess_search_theme_form but I don't know how can I remove DIV tags via this function or the other related functions.

Comment: You have to look for the function which is building the HTML code. Most often I take a copy of this function and implement my own template file or theme function. Removing a part of the HTML later on is often more dificult than building it the right way in the first place.

Comment: How to override theme functions? copy them to template.php, rename them from `theme_whatever` to `YOURTHEME_whatever`. Also, check http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6761/theme-function-overrides-and-preprocess-functions-for-the-non-programmer

Comment: Thanks a lot BetaRide. Can you put an example here ?